# Windows Server 2008 R2 - what role for Backburner Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2008, services, 3ds-max

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 which I use as Remote Desktop Host. users log onto it and work on it.

Now, additionally to that, I'd also like to run a simple server application on it which is implemented as a Windows service. So, it's an application that I can install as service and while it runs it accepts some connections on a certain port.

This service is **Blackburner Manager** from 3ds Max.

My question is, in server 2008 R2, what "Role" do I have to setup in order to do that and in which user account do I need to install the service? I want it to run whenever the server machine boots up.

Comment: This depends entirely on the server, Mat. When servers are installed (take SQL Server, for instance), all necessary server-related accounts and roles are created for you. You don't usually need to do anything to have the server up and running in its own security space. Other servers may include instructions on how to do this. You need to specify what server you are thinking installing, for us to be able to help. Alternatively, you may want to check the ServerFault forum and bring your question there.

Comment: it's the 'backburner manager' service which is installed alongside 3ds max. it's a small application that manages 3d rendering across multiple rendernodes. I used to have it run on my workstation, now i'd like to install it on my server instead.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the server's function: You can literally start with no roles installed. The one function you mention, "Remote Desktop Host", is actually called the "Remote Desktop Services" role, and the Remote Desktop application in Windows is used to use this service. This role was formerly known as "Terminal Services".

Even without that role, Server 2008 R2 comes with the ability for two people to simultaneously log in using Remote Desktop, however, if you wish to use that role for additional simultaneous users, you will need to install the role, and purchase separate Remote Desktop Services Client Access Licenses for each user, in addition to the regular Server 2008 user CAL's.

When you purchase these Remote Desktop Services CAL's, you will be able to enter them into you Remote Desktop Services license server. Without this, you only have a 120-day trial period, which is fully functional, but will cease to work after that without the license server and licenses entered into it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services

As the others said, if it requires any roles, which I doubt based on a Google search, it will probably install them automatically, or the documentation will spell it out. Most ordinary applications do not require special roles unless they are integrated in Active Directory, then they require those related roles. I believe the answer to your basic question is "none".